# Sonar Eclipse plugin using the wrong quality profile as Sonar server

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

We have a sonar server set up with lots of projects and a few different quality profiles. We just discovered the sonar-eclipse plugin and we're loving it -- except, it doesn't seem to be using the quality profile for our project -- it's using "Sonar way" -- when we do local analysis.

```
13:32:00.899 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
```

The sonar server is version 3.5, sonar-eclipse is 3.1.1.20130521-1304-RELEASE. Eclipse platform is 3.7.2.v20120207-1839.

Any ideas what might be up with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, this is unhappily a known issue when using Sonar Eclipse in local mode on Maven module : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARIDE-366.

Comment: Thank you. What's the timeline for fixing this issue? I see that it's targeted to 3.3 -- when will that be released? In the meantime, is there a workaround?

Comment: 3.3 should be available at the end of July !

Comment: Thank you @freddy -- we'll look forward to that, and just deal with the "Sonar way" on local analysis in the meantime.